# Clojure Spam Filter

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement Bayseian classifier in Clojure. I am using Collective Intelligence book as a reference. Here is my code:

```
    (ns spam-filter.model.classifier
    (:require [clojure.string :as st]))

    ;Counts of feature/category combinations
    (def fc (atom {}))
    @fc


    ;Counts of documents in each category
    ;How many times every classification has been used
    (def cc (atom {}))
    @cc

    ;extracts features from the text
    (defn getwords
      "Divides the text on any character that isn't a letter.
      Converted to lowercase"
      [doc]
      (let [words (st/split doc #" ")
            less-than-20 (filter #(< (count %) 20) words)
            final-words (filter #(> (count %) 2) less-than-20)]
        (reduce (fn [final-map word]
                  (assoc final-map (.toLowerCase word) 1))
                {}
                final-words)))


    ;increase the count of a feature/category pair
    (defn incf
      [f cat] 
    (if (not (contains? @fc f))
      (swap! fc #(assoc % f {})))
    (if (not (get-in @fc [f cat]))
      (swap! fc #(assoc-in % [f cat] 0)))
    (swap! fc #(update-in % [f cat] inc)))



    ;increase the count of a category
    (defn incc
     [cat]
    (if (not (contains? @cc cat))
    (swap! cc #(assoc % cat 0)))
    (swap! cc #(update % cat inc)))


    ;The number of times a feature has appeared in a category
    (defn fcount
      [f cat]
    (let [num (get-in @fc [f cat])]
      (if (not (nil? num))
        num
        0.0)))



    ; The number of items in a category
    (defn catcount
      [cat]
    (let [n-of-items (get @cc cat)]
      (if (not (nil? n-of-items))
        n-of-items
        0)))




    ; The total numbers of items
    (defn totalcount
      []
    (reduce + (vals @cc)))



    ; The list of all categories
    (defn categories
    []
    (keys @cc))



    (defn train
      [t cat]
    (incc cat)
    (let [ws (keys (getwords t))]
      (for [w ws] (incf w cat))))



    (defn train1
      [t cat]
      (incc cat)
      (let [features (keys (getwords t))]
        (map incf features (repeat (count features) cat))))



    (defn sampletrain
    []
    [(train "Nobody owns the water." "good")
      (train "the quick rabbit jumps fences" "good")
      (train "buy pharmaceuticals now" "bad")
      (train "make quick money at the online casino" "bad")
      (train "the quick brown fox jumps" "good")])

    @fc
    @cc

    (sampletrain)


    ; probability that a word is in particular category
    ; Pr(word | classification)
    (defn fprob
      [f cat]
    (if (= (catcount cat) 0)
      0
    (float (/ (fcount f cat) (catcount cat)))))

    (fprob "quick" "good")



    ; probability that a word is in particular category
    ; assumed probability 0.5
    (defn weightedprob
      [f cat fprob]
    (let [weight 1
          ap 0.5
          basicprob (fprob f cat)
          totals (reduce + (vals (get @fc f)))
          bp (/ (+ (* weight ap) (* totals basicprob)) (+ weight totals))]
    bp))



    ; Extracts features and multiplies all
    ; their probabilities together to get
    ; an overall probability Pr(Document | Category)
    (defn docprob
      [item cat]
      (let [features (keys (getwords item))]

      (loop [features features
             p 1]
        (if (empty? features)
          p
          (recur
           (rest features)
           (* p (weightedprob (first features) cat fprob)))))))


    ;returns product of Pr(Document | Category) and Pr(Category)
    (defn prob
      [item cat]
      (let [catprob (/ (catcount cat) (totalcount))
            docprob (docprob item cat)]
        (* docprob catprob)))

    (prob "quick rabbit" "good")
    (prob "quick rabbit" "bad")


    (def thresholds (atom {}))


    (defn setthreshold
      [cat t]
    (swap! thresholds #(assoc % cat t)))


    (defn getthreshold
      [cat]
    (if (contains? @thresholds cat)
      (get @thresholds cat)
    1.0))

    (getthreshold "bad")


    (defn classify
      [item]
    (let [probs (atom {})
          max (atom 0.0)
          best (atom nil)]
    (map (fn [cat] ((swap! probs #(assoc % cat (prob item cat)))
                    (when (> (get @probs cat) @max)
                        (swap! max #(let [% (get @probs cat)] %))
                        (swap! best #(let [% cat] %))))) (categories))
    (map (fn [cat] (if (> (* (get @probs cat) (getthreshold @best)) (get @probs @best))
                      nil
                      @best))) (filter #(not= % @best) (categories))))



    (classify "quick money")
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with my last function classify. When I call this function with argument "quick money" I should get this document classified as bad. But instead I got:

```
("good" "bad")
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is lazy so if you're calling it without realizing the resulting lazy sequence it has no effect. You're doing that in a couple of places. If you have to call a function against each elements of a collection, for side effects only, consider using `run!` instead.

More generally, your algorithm implementation depends on mutating various global atoms. This is highly unidiomatic in clojure which makes it hard to read and difficult to reason about. Try passing in and returning the expected state instead. That way you wouldn't have your `map` problem in the first place.

There's also a bunch of race conditions in your code related to forms like

```
  (defn incc
     [cat]
    (if (not (contains? @cc cat))
    (swap! cc #(assoc % cat 0))) ; no guarantee that @cc wasn't updated 
                                 ; between here and the contains? line above
    (swap! cc #(update % cat inc)))
```

This code can be simplified and made error-free using `fnil`

```
(defn incc
     [cat]
     (swap! cc update cat (fnil inc 0)))
```